# Search and display all the uppercase characters in the string in Oracle using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following string/char/varchar:

```
'abhuvuyvvBDUYWGFEGFkmnxsjanchbYYSG'
```

How do I write a SQL statement to extract only uppercase characters from the above string using SQL in Oracle:

Desired output:

```
B
D
U
Y
W
G
F
E
G
F
Y
Y
S
G
```

Comment: Sounds like homework? Could you please at least explain what you have tried and what did not work as expected?

Comment: Please include your current attempt and explain what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to what Barbaros suggested (hierarchical query), but maybe a little bit *safer* if your character set isn't ASCII. For example, that condition (ASCII values between 65 and 90 wouldn't *catch* Croatian uppercase letters).

```
with test (col) as
  (select 'ĐŠŽĆČabhuvuyvvBDUYWGFEGFkmnxsjanchbYYSG' from dual)
select substr(col, level, 1) result
from test
where substr(col, level, 1) = upper(substr(col, level, 1))
connect by level <= length(col);
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3R4uWrKg).

Answer (score 0):

You might use a hierarchial query along with `SUBSTR()` so as to read the letters one-by-one while determining their numerical values by `ASCII()` function to fit within a range such as

```
WITH t(col) AS
(
 SELECT 'abhuvuyvvBDUYWGFEGFkmnxsjanchbYYSG' FROM dual
)
 SELECT SUBSTR(col,level,1) AS result
   FROM t
  WHERE ASCII(SUBSTR(col,level,1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 -- interval for uppercase letters of English alphabet
 CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the upper-case characters in a column that contains only mixed-case alphabetic characters then use:

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(
         column_name,
         'Aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
         'A'
       ) AS upper_case_characters
FROM   table_name;
```

or, for any characters (but it will be slower than using `TRANSLATE`):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         column_name,
         '[^[:upper:]]'
       ) AS upper_case_characters
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name) AS
SELECT 'abhuvuyvvBDUYWGFEGFkmnxsjanchbYYSG' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| UPPER_CASE_CHARACTERS |
| --- |
| BDUYWGFEGFYYSG |

---

If you want a carriage return between every upper-case character then:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(
         BOTH CHR(10) FROM
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           column_name,
           '[^[:upper:]]*([[:upper:]])?',
           CHR(10) || '\1'
         )
       ) AS upper_case_characters
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

| UPPER_CASE_CHARACTERS |
| --- |
| B D U Y W G F E G F Y Y S G |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nFN_nn3x)